How to automatically compute a signal with withComputed in ngrx/signals Library with SelectionModel Changes?
I have recently started using the ngrx/signals library in my Angular project, and I am trying to automatically compute a state called countSelectedRows using the withComputed function. However, I am encountering an issue where the state does not recognize the changes in my SelectionModel.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
export const StackOverflowStore = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState({
    tableRows: [],
    selection: new SelectionModel(true, []),
  }),

  withComputed(({ tableRows, selection }) => ({
    countSelectedRows: computed(() => {
      return tableRows().filter(row => selection().isSelected(row)).length;
    })
  })),
);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let row of store.tableRows()">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleSelection(row)" />
      {{ row.name }}
    </div>
    <p>Selected Rows Count: {{ store.countSelectedRows() }}</p>
  `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  store = inject(StackOverflowStore);

  toggleSelection(row: any) {
    this.store.selection().toggle(row);
  }
}

The withComputed function does not seem to detect changes in the SelectionModel. Is it possible to implement this using ngrx/signals or do I need to find another way to detect changes in selection.changed?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
